# Stretch background-image of parent to pseudo elements?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm trying to make the `background-image` of a parent stretched to a pseudo element.

I'm currently using the code below and it works in a sense that it's using the same image but the placement is not correct (see screenshot). I'd like this to be seamless.

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.parent::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  background: inherit;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

[image]

Setting the parent's `background-attachement` to `fixed` seems to make it work but then I get an unwanted parallax effect on the parent.

Is there a way to make this work in a way that allows me to stretch the background image but avoid parallax? All help much appreciated!

Comment: You know that with `bottom: -15px;` you are positioning the pseudo child element out of parent ?

Comment: Thanks, yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I want the background image to overlap onto the next element. That's why I'm trying to use the ::after.

Comment: Maybe add html structure then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the pseudo element cover the whole element and only its background will be visible:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1018/800/800);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  height:100px;
}

.parent::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top:0;
  background: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

</div>
```